# Trying to pass a variable to a view, but nothing is shown in the view - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to pass a variable to a view, but nothing is shown in the view.

**Controller Code:**

```
public function postCreatePost(Request $request, $wordID)
{
    $postsInWord = Post::where('words_id', $wordID)->get();
    return redirect()->back()->with('postsInWord', $postsInWord);
```

**View code:**

```
@if (isset($postsInWord))
    @foreach ($postsInWord as $postsInWord)
    <p>{{$postsInWord->body}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send variable with redirect.

Although you can pass session with some data like follow.

```
return redirect()->back()->with('data', 'some kind of data');
```

And then you can fetch the data from blade template using:

```
@if (session('data'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('data') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

For more: https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: Tried the session code, still empty .. not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `return` statement..

```
return redirect()->back()->with('data', ['postsInWord']);
```

Try this one..

Comment: Plz try to simply print the array In controller as well as in blade..it will be better to debug. And plz check is there any error occurred or just blank page displayed?