# Laravel 5.1 Redirect with variable

Tags: php, laravel, variables, redirect, laravel-5.1

I am trying to redirect in Laravel like this:

in my controller:

```
  $state = false;
  return redirect()->route('newPr')->with('errorMessageDuration', 'error', $state);
```

and in my view I try to get it like this:

```
<input id="PrId" type="text" value="{{ isset($state) ? $state : '' }}">
```

but somehow it does not work, it keeps being empty.

I want it to be saved permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `withErrors()` with an associative array instead, like so:

```
return redirect()->route('newPr')->withErrors(compact('state'));
```

Then you can simply use the $errors variable in your view.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation):

> The $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used. The
>   $errors variable will be an instance of Illuminate\Support\MessageBag.
>   For more information on working with this object, [check out its
>   documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#working-with-error-messages).

Comment: did not work:<input id="PrId" type="text" value="{{ isset($error) ? $error : '' }}">

Comment: `$errors`, plural. And you can safely use it without checking if it `isset`, because it's always available in your views. I'll update the answer with docs.

Comment: can I also use this: `return redirect()->back()->withErrors(compact('state'));`

Comment: Sure you can. That's what I do.

Comment: What do you mean? Save what and where?

Comment: I get this message after changing `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` I made this `return redirect()->back()->withErrors(compact('state'));<input id="PrId" type="text" value="{{ $errors }}">`

Comment: the value in the input is probably not saved after one reloads the page

Comment: Please read the docs I sent you. $errors is an object, not a string. So use `$errors->state` instead.

Comment: To have it always available you need to rethink the whole approach. It doesn't make sense to always display errors to the user, it only does when he did something wrong. So if instead you just want a default $state value, just set it directly in your controller method that is serving the form.

Comment: hmm how would you accomplish this in a controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116769/discussion-between-regulareverydaynormalguy-and-john-doe-2).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the session to display it,

```
<input id="PrId" type="text" value="{{ isset(session($state)) ? $session($state) : '' }}">
```

Comment: hi, I get this message  `Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead)`

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions.

```
$request->session()->flash('error', 'Some error message');
return redirect()->route('newPr');
```

And in the view:

```
@if (session('error'))
    The error is {{ session('error') }}
@endif
```

Comment: @JohnDoe2, yes by using `put` instead of `flash`.

Answer (score 1):

`with` method takes 2 parameters. The 1st one being the `key` and 2nd one `value` Or if the 1st parameter is an array its `key` will be the `key` and `value` will be the `value`.

So in your case you can do `->with('state', $state)` Or `->with(compact('state'))`

`with` method will flush this value to the `session` so in order to retrieve the value you need to get it from `session` like this `session('state')`

You can pass any value in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send variable with redirect, but if you want try with session.

Take a look at my old answer here: [Trying to pass a variable to a view, but nothing is shown in the view - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204076/trying-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-view-but-nothing-is-shown-in-the-view-laravel?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Tried your suggestion did not work                 `return redirect()->back()->with($state);@if (session('state'))
                    <input id="PrId" type="text" value="{{ session('state') }}">
                @endif`