# laravel redirect with compact does not pass variable

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

i'm trying to pass an array with compact to a view  , i know i can do it like this `return view('dashboard',compact('user'));` but i want to use redirect . When i use `redirect('dashboard')->with(compact('user'));` it displays an error `undefined variable user` on my dashboard view . what could be the problem ? any help please ?

please find below my method which redirect to my dashboard view

```
public function store(UsercreateRequest $request)
{

     $image =$request->file('image');
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        if($image->isValid())
        {

            $way=public_path('images');

            $extension=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();



                $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                //echo $name;

            if(file_exists($way.'/'.$name))
            {

                if($image->move($way,$name))
            {

                //echo'ok '; //75485205
                //echo $name;
                    $data= array_merge($request->all(),['image'=>$name]);
                $user=$this->userRepository->store($data);
                return redirect('dashboard')->with(compact('user'));
             }

            }



        }

    }
    return redirect('signup')->withErrors(" L'enrisgrement n'a pas abouti !");
    //
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260375/laravel-5-1-redirect-with-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return redirect('dashboard')->with(compact('user'));

You cannot do that. The route `dashboard` will have it's own controller method which would load a view. So passing data during redirect would have no effect. You need to return the view response for it to work like you've said so yourself.

Generally when a new item is stored the redirect would to be to the newly created item. Since you're creating a new user, you could probably redirect to the user's profile page if you have one.

```
return redirect('users/' . $user->id);
```

Comment: i used `session` instead and there no logic redirecting user to dashboard after registration  so redirected to login instead . `return redirect('login')->with('user',$user);`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but in case someone runs into this page and needs an answer: You can pass an associative array to `with`:

```
redirect('dashboard')->with([
    'user' => $user,
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'dinner' => 'dolma'
]);
```

If `return redirect('login')->with('user',$user);` works for you and you can use `$user` in your 'login' view, it means that your setup is correct and you will be able to use `$foo` and `$dinner` as well.

Comment: i believe you not even tried this before posting, $user is empty with this implementation, it will be stored on session instead